# Why is my Pentaho server running slow, on Linux?

Tags: java, linux, memory, pentaho, pentaho-design-studio

I am using Pentaho 4.8 and this is the configuration in my `start-pentaho.sh`

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000 -Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000"
```

Can anybody please explain what these parameters mean ???

```
-Xms256m 
-Xmx1024m 
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

I did not find any particular reason, why my server on my Linux machine is responding very slow. I thought may be increasing the size here might help , but I don't want to change until I understand the parameters, if anybody have any suggestion for increasing my server speed, then please help me

Comment: If your service is slow, I suggest you performance profile it, or at least monitoring your application with VisualVM.  You can try increasing the maximum memory size, but I suspect this will make little difference.

Comment: ...Ideally this should be migrated to superuser.com

Comment: @KentPawar : how can i migrate it , or i have to create a new question there ??

Comment: @HussainAkhtarWahid Well a user on this site with a high reputation can migrate it.. Such questions would be better suited for superuser as it is not a programming question and may get negative votes on this site..